# How to change a div background image when hover an other div

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have using one **div** to display a image.  the **id** name of the div is **first**, i gave both background image and hover image using css. now i have to hover an first div image when hovering an another div.

here below the example

**`<div id="first"></div>`**

default background image of first div is - bgimg.jpg

The hover image of first div is - hoverbgimg.jpg

THE ANOTHER DIV IS **`<div id="second"></div>`**

here when i am **hovering second div** the **first div image should be change**.

Comment: Can you use jQuery or do you want pure JavaScript?

Comment: Can you please add an jsfiddle ?

Comment: you mean when you hover second div, your first div should be hovered and second div should remain as it is ?

Comment: @SpiderCode - yes exactly.

Comment: @Marc Audent - it can be css or JavaScript.

Comment: depending on your html structure, maybe this is working for you: http://jsfiddle.net/w5nMj/3/

Comment: @user3717611 : You can achieve this using second div's mousehover and mouseout event. Have a look at my answer. Hope you will get the solution.

Comment: <div> <div id='first'><?php while() { ?> </div> <div id='second'></div>  <div id='first'></div> <?php } ?></div> above the code for example the while loop running 5 times mean how can we do fro this, tell me plz..

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done through CSS only.

Add below JS code in Js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#second").on("hover", function(){
     $("first").css("background", "imagename.jpg");
   });

});
```

Dont forget to include jquery file first.

Comment: jquery solution. people will give down vote, because OP didn't mentioned jquery in his question. I got experience in other question today.

Comment: He linked `javascript` as a post tag...Jquery is a perfectly acceptable option.

Comment: oh really. kindly check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161011/when-enter-keydown-click-button/24161086#24161086. Initially he mentioned javascript only. I have given jquery answers. Then all over the place i got downvote. No idea why is like that?

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible if you try and work with jquery. try this line of code, just copy and paste:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#dd").hover(function(){
$("#ddd").css("background-color","yellow");
},function(){
$("#ddd").css("background-color","pink");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dd">Hover the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</div>
<div id="ddd">Hover the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can catch the hover event in the second div and implement an action for the mouseover and mouseout over the first div:

```
$( "#second" ).hover(
         function() {
            $("#first").mouseover();
          }, function() {
            $("#first").mouseout();
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at below code sample:

**Using JavaScript:**

```
<div id ="first" style="min-height: 100px;width: 100px; background-image: url('../Content/images/bgImage.JPG') "></div>

<div id ="second" style="width:100px;height: 100px;background-color:#191970" onmouseover="changeFirst(true)" onmouseout="changeFirst(false)"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function changeFirst(isHover) {
        if (isHover) {
            document.getElementById('first').style.backgroundImage = "url('../Content/images/hoverBgImage.png')";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('first').style.backgroundImage = "url('../Content/images/bgImage.JPG')";
        }
    }

</script>
```

**Using JQuery:**

```
<div id="first" style="min-height: 100px; width: 100px; background-image: url('../Content/images/bgImage.JPG')"></div>

<div id="second" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #191970"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


    $('#second').hover(function () {
        $('#first').css('background-image', "url('../Content/images/hoverBgImage.png')");
    },
        function () {
            $('#first').css('background-image', "url('../Content/images/bgImage.JPG')");
        }
    );

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, your java script code is working fine. but the problem is i am displaying both first and second div in while loop. for example: both first and second div is one set, when i am hovering 5th set mean the 5th set first div only have to hover. so please help me to do that.

Comment: <div> <div id='first'><?php while() { ?> </div> <div id='second'></div>  <div id='first'></div> <?php } ?></div> above the code for example the while loop running 5 times mean how can we do fro this, tell me plz..

Comment: <div id="fulldiv">
<?php
$i=0;
$query=mysql_query("select * from tables where main='$main'")or die("ERROR!1!");
while($queryrow=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $i++;
    $main=$queryrow['main'];             
    ?>
    <div class="sub" align="center"><a href=""><div id="first"></div><br /><font id="second"><?php echo $main; ?></font></a></div>
    <?php  } ?>    
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>